# Not able to access Samba server from one Win10 laptop

Tags: networking, windows-10, raspberry-pi, samba

I have a samba server running on a raspberry pi in my home network. I can access it from my two laptops running Win10. These are in my home WORKGROUP.

Now I have another work laptop running Win10. I cannot connect to the Samba share from it. The Pi does not appear in the list when I see it in the network on this laptop.

I'm sure it is due to some security setting on this laptop, but I am not able to find out.

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify "I cannot connect to the Samba share". Have you tried and failed to connect directly by IP address? Or is this based entirely on "the Pi not appearing in the list"?

Comment: I cannot connect from Windows Explorer, the share is not listed. Also, providing IP also does not resolve.

Comment: IPs don't need to "resolve". Do you get a specific error message if you try to access either `\\ip.add.re.ss` or `\\ip.add.re.ss\ShareName` via Windows Explorer?

Comment: @grawity, it does not work in that way as well. It works from other laptops in the network,

Answer (score 0):

Check if network discovery is enabled.

[screenshot with parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yve9.png)

Comment: Thanks, @Konstantin. The Network Discovery is on. I suspect something with some other policy, but not sure of.